# CipherMail Secure WebMail

Tags: email, security, encryption, webmail

I have Installed Virtual appliance of CipherMail gateway. As they mentioned in there document that secure web mail is add-on to virtual appliance and it can be accessable with 8443 port but im not able to get the secure webmail  portal. Do I need to configure anything to get the Secure web mail portal.

Comment: This is not a programming related question and should not be on stackoverflow. Please find another fitting stackexchange site.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: @Connum thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that feature comes with enterprise edition. That's why not able to access the secure webmail.